# Flex/AS3 Setting default value for empty form

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Currently I have a form in a window like this:

```
<mx:Form>
    <mx:FormItem label="Reference">
    <mx:TextInput id="reference" width="100%"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Command">
    <mx:TextInput id="command" width="100%"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Command Field">
    <mx:TextInput id="commandField" width="100%"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Parameter">
    <mx:TextInput id="parameter" width="100%"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Extra Command">
    <mx:TextInput id="commandExtra" width="100%"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Sequence Number">
    <mx:TextInput id="seq" width="100%"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

Is there any way to change the default value of a blank form entry from `null` to some other value?

Comment: I don't want the user to be able to change the default value. Text="xxx" puts in xxx and shows it to the user. If I could hide the default xxx value from the user it would accomplish the same goal

Comment: @David, you don't want the user to change the default value? Then why are you using a text input?

Comment: I'm saying if I make a default value by using text="xxx", then the user will be able to see "xxx" in the form when they want to enter information. If the user deletes the "xxx" for some reason, a blank value will be entered instead, which I don't want. I just wanted to see if there was some easy way to make the "blank" value something other than 0.

Comment: @David, the default value is `null`.  I'm not sure where you're getting a `0` from.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I was transferring it over to XML and to make a long story short it was turning it into a 0. I'll edit the question but I still would like to know if it is possible to change the default value from `null` to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function that replaces the functionality of TextInput.text

Something along the lines of:

```
public function set text():String {
    return formatText(_text);
}

private function formatText(textToFormat:String):String {
    return (textToFormat == null)? "" : textToFormat;
}
```

Which, of course could also be simplified to:

```
public function set text():String {
    return (_text == null)? "" : _text;
}
```

This would require that the _text property of FormItem is protected (and not private).  If that's not the case, there are ways to work around it.

Clearly, there are better ways to solve this problem but I just wanted to throw out an idea.

Hope it helps in some way or form,

--gMale